# Wifi not working on new ASUS vivobook 17

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus

Ethernet works, but Ubuntu thinks I don't have any WiFi.  I do and it works on Windows.
The bluetooth  is also not working.

[This is my laptop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07661CYPD).

Everything is updated, here's some extra info I noticed were asked on similar posts:

```
ecoologic@ecoolaptop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB]    
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17.2 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.6 kB]
Fetched 106 kB in 2s (46.3 kB/s)            
Reading package lists... Done
ecoologic@ecoolaptop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 02801
ecoologic@ecoolaptop:~$  sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: b0:6e:bf:1f:d0:3a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.0.0.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:279 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef204000-ef204fff memory:ef200000-ef203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:ef100000-ef10ffff
ecoologic@ecoolaptop:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
ecoologic@ecoolaptop:~$ uname -r
4.13.0-36-generic
ecoologic@ecoolaptop:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 24FD
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00001012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00003E01bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00003E02bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000850bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000950bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000930bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000910bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00008130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000810bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00008010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00008050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00008110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000150bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000050bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd000010D0bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00001130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00001110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*
ecoologic@ecoolaptop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
```

Any help is appreciated, even something that allows me to dig deeper.

**OT:**
I installed Ubuntu on quite a few machines for my friends, but I guess I always got lucky, maybe because they were old laptops.  Work always gave me a Mac, so I am pretty excited to be back on Linux - If I can this these problems.

Thank you very, very much.

Comment: We need more details about your wireless. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280`

Comment: @chili555 thank you very much, it's ` Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]` (added to the question too).  Much appreciated

Comment: I have re-opened https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+bug/1745081

Comment: how is this still a thing? i bought myself an asus vivobook 17 (r702q) and got the latest HWE kernel-edge. and no wifi. I don't see how this is a duplicate question. the 'duplicate' has a completely different model. and just installing some random driver for a random wifi card doesn't seem like a smart idea to me. especially since I don't even know what is in the laptop.